# Can I add a description for a new tag I created?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki, tag-creation

If I ask a question with a newly created tag, am I then able to add a description describing the tag? I have the reputation required to create a tag.

Comment: Have you tried? Do you know how to? Are you asking whether you're prohibited from it or are you asking where to go to do so?

Comment: @Catija Sorry I should have mentioned I have the reputation needed to create a tag. I haven't tried it because I don't have a question to ask just yet requiring it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Editing tag wikis are part of the [20K trusted user tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) but any registered user can submit an edit suggestion at any reputation level (and earn reputation points for it if the edit is accepted).

This means that, while you can't have your edit go live immediately - yes, creating a description where there is none counts as an "edit" - if it's accepted, it will eventually appear on the site. For corroboration, see the [suggested edits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> #### Who can suggest an edit?
>
> - Registered users without the [edit privilege](//meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) (2000 rep) can suggest edits to any post or tag wiki.
> - Registered users who have the [edit privilege](//meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) but are not [trusted users](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (<20000 rep) can suggest edits to tag wikis.
> - Anonymous users can suggest edits to any post *more than [10 minutes old](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97221/dont-allow-suggested-edits-until-post-is-one-hour-old/97228#97228)*. These edits are attributed to [the Community ♦ user](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) upon approval. They cannot suggest edits to tag wikis.

When you do suggest an edit, keep in mind the guidance on the edit page (right sidebar) and in the [linked blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/).

To find the page where you can write a Tag Wiki Excerpt and a Tag Wiki, click on the tag and then click on "improve tag info", the second option in the Tag Wiki Excerpt box. You can also get to it by clicking on "learn more" and then scrolling to the bottom of the page, where there's an edit button "Edit Tag Info".

Comment: Technically, the Community user "creates" the tag wiki as soon as you submit your suggestion - then your suggestion is considered as an edit to the blank wiki.